# Sorting ArrayList full of objects by their id using Collections.sort(arrayListName)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, comparable

I have an inventory class which creates an ArrayList full of objects Item, which is a class as well. I know that I have to call
    `Collections.sort(items);` in order to sort the ArrayList (it's called items by the way). The assignment says that I have to use an interface on the Item class, I don't know whether or not to implement Comparator or Comparable and then what to write for either the `compareTo()` method or the `compare()` method respectfully. Also I have the `Collections.sort(items)` call right after I declare my ArrayList, is this okay?

Edit: My teacher just clarified that she wants us to implement `Comparable<Item>` on the Item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to implement `Comparable` and it will work `Collections.sort`

If you need a new comparator and don't want to use the `Comparable` you can create a new `Comparator` and use it like: `Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator())`

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{
    
    private String fruitName;
    private String fruitDesc;
    private int quantity;
    
    public Fruit(String fruitName, String fruitDesc, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    
    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }
    public String getFruitDesc() {
        return fruitDesc;
    }
    public void setFruitDesc(String fruitDesc) {
        this.fruitDesc = fruitDesc;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {
    
        int compareQuantity = ((Fruit) compareFruit).getQuantity(); 
        
        //ascending order
        return this.quantity - compareQuantity;
        
        //descending order
        //return compareQuantity - this.quantity;
        
    }   
}
```

source: [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Comment: So I've got Item implements Comparable<Item> and then in the class I defined compareTo() as 

public int compareTo (Item other)
 {
  if (this.id.compareToIgnoreCase((other.getId())) == 0)
   return 0;
     else if (this.id.compareToIgnoreCase(other.getId()) > 0)
         return 1;
     else
         return -1;
 }

Now do I just called Collections.sort(items) in my Inventory class?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's giving me an error when I write Collections.sort(items); it says  - Syntax error on token "items", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Wait I just got it, I was putting it in the body of the class, thanks!

Comment: I hate solutions with links. Its not a solution. One of your link is Dead

Comment: @trixo updated. removed the bad link and I added a brief implementation from one of the links specifying the source :)

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 8:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
// add elements
Collections.sort(items, Comparator.comparingLong(Item::getId));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of `Collections.sort()` .

[Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,java.util.Comparator%29) . One takes a `List`and another takes a `List` and an instance of `Comparator`. The single argument `sort()` will expect your class to have implemented [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and overridden the [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method. The two argument `sort()` method expects an instance of [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), wherein you have implemented the `Comparator` and overridden its [compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,T%29) method.

An object should implement `Comparable` if that is the clear natural way to sort the class, and anyone would need to sort the class would generally want to do it that way.

If, however, the sorting was an unusual use case of the class or there can be multiple sort orders then a `Comparator` is a better option.

*Also I have the Collections.sort(items) call right after I declare my ArrayList, is this okay?*

You will call `sort()` when you need to sort the `List`. Adding items after `sort()` won't automatically sort the `List` to accommodate the change in ordering of list items due to addition of new elements.

Sample implementation:

```
public int compareTo (Item other) { 
   return new Integer(this.getID()).compareTo(new Integer(other.getID()));
}
```

Comment: I have to use the one that just calls Collections.sort(items)

Comment: Ok , but based on what field ?

Comment: What do you mean, I don't understand sorry